# Postgres - Select CASE when & order by the same column probme

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the follwing SQL, and It's giving me `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "﻿rownum" does not exist`.

```
SELECT *, (case when col1 = 'A' then
                    1
           when col1 = 'B' then
                    2
           else
                    3
           end) as rownum
from table1 
order by colb, rownum, colc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some RDBMS's do not recognize aliased columns in the `order by` clause. You can subquery what you have:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ... AS rownum FROM table1) AS A ORDER BY colb, rownum, colc
```

In Postgresql, I believe you can also do:

```
SELECT (case ...) as rownum, * FROM table1 ORDER BY colb, 1, colc
```